# How to load external r library from Rserve java client

Tags: java, r, rserve

I am new to both R and Java.I need to know is there any method to load R library from javaclient of Rserve for my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run any command with the client that you want to run in R. It is simply communicating over a socket with the server. The server has started an embedded R process that you can communicate with.

```
RConnection c = new RConnection();
c.eval("library(\"plyr\")")
```